# Laravel Lighthouse Graphql HasOne nested relation not working

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I am trying to get a HasOne relation to work in Laravel Lighthouse GraphQL.
It doesn't work. The mutation does not give an error, but also doesn't update the relation (the employee id stays the same, while I want it to change to 2):

```graphql
mutation {
  updateAccount(input: {
    id: 12
    employee: {
      connect: 2
    }
  }) {
    id
    employee {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

My schema looks like this:

```graphql
type Mutation {
    updateAccount(input: UpdateAccount! @spread): Account! @update
}

input UpdateAccountInput {
    id: ID!
    employee: CreateEmployeeRelationInput @hasOne
}

input CreateEmployeeRelationInput {
    connect: ID!
}

type Account {
    id: ID!
    ...
    employee: Employee! @hasOne
}

type Employee {
    id: ID!
    ...
    account: Account @belongsTo
}
```

The Account and Employee models looks like this:

```php
class Account extends Model
{
    public function employee(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\Employee::class, 'account_id');
    }
}

class Employee extends Model
{
    public function account(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Account::class, 'account_id');
    }
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.
So far I've tried to add/remove `@hasOne`, or change `ID!` to `[ID!]!`, but nothing works.

Comment: What do your `Account` and `Employee` types look like?

Comment: I've added the ```Account``` and ```Employee``` types to the question (only the fields that seem relevant). Would these types make any difference?

Comment: The only thing I can see in your code that doesn't match mine is your use of the `@hasOne` directive in the input.

Comment: Are you sure it is the same? If I read the documentation correctly, what I try to do is not yet possible in Lighthouse. I've opened an issue here: https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse/issues/1109 .

Answer (score 0):

I found out that Lighthouse does not provide the functionality that I wanted, because Laravel does not provide it, and Lighthouse tries to mirror the Laravel functionality.

More information can be found in this answer to this issue: https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse/issues/1109#issuecomment-570544848

In short:
A `hasOne` relation does **not** have an `associate()` or `dissociate()` method.
A `hasMany` relation does **not** have `sync()`, `attach()` or `detach()`.
But the `belongsTo` relation **does** have `associate()` and `dissociate()`.

Therefore if an account **hasOne** employee, I con **not** do this:

```graphql
mutation {
  updateAccount(input: {
    id: 12
    employee: {
      connect: 2
    }
  }) {
    id
    solis_id
    employee {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Also if an Account **hasMany** employees, I can **not** do this:

```graphql
mutation {
  updateAccount(input: {
    id: 12
    employees: {
      connect: [2, 3]
    }
  }) {
    id
    solis_id
    employees {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

But what I **can** do to achieve the same result is this:

```graphql
mutation {
  updateEmployee(input: {
    id: 2
    account: {
      connect: 2
    }
  }) {
    id
    account {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Man, I'm having the same issue but I'm not able to solve it :(

Comment: @mentamarindo I wish you good luck! I will not be able to help, because I stopped using PHP for GraphQL (switched over to JS which is not easier).

Comment: If JS is not easier why you switched?

Comment: Good question. Mainly because I found out that I like JavaScript more. I chose Nexus+Prisma which looks promising to me (full typescript support for one thing) but which is still rough around the edges.